# Eclipse Juno docked windows

Tags: eclipse-juno

I started using eclipse Juno a month ago but still can't get used to the sliding, popping docked windows. Especially when you debug and hit a breakpoint couple docked windows pop and focus is lost. Is there a way to suppress this annoying behavior?

Comment: Maybe you can better explain the problem? I don't really understand, a screenshot would probably help.

Comment: I have the same problem. The actual problem is that, while compiling or debugging the program, console window pops-up. And when I try to minimize that window, the editor window also minimized.